# Idiomatic way to reduce a list of pairs to a map of keys and their aggregated count?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to recreate Hadoop's [word count](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/mapred_tutorial.html) map / reduce logic in a simple Scala program for learning

This is what I have so far

```
val words1 = "Hello World Bye World"      
val words2 = "Hello Hadoop Goodbye Hadoop"

val input = List(words1,words2)           
val mapped = input.flatMap(line=>line.split(" ").map(word=>word->1))
    //> mapped  : List[(String, Int)] = List((Hello,1), (World,1), (Bye,1), 
    //                                       (World,1), (Hello,1), (Hadoop,1), 
    //                                       (Goodbye,1), (Hadoop,1))

mapped.foldLeft(Map[String,Int]())((sofar,item)=>{
    if(sofar.contains(item._1)){
        sofar.updated(item._1, item._2 + sofar(item._1))
    }else{
        sofar + item
    }
})                              
    //>Map(Goodbye -> 1, Hello -> 2, Bye -> 1, Hadoop -> 2, World -> 2)
```

This seems to work, but I'm sure there is a more idiomatic way to handle the reduce part (foldLeft)

I was thinking about perhaps a multimap,  but I have a feeling Scala has a way to do this easily

Is there? e.g. **a way to add to a map, and if the key exists, instead of replacing it, adding the value to the existing value**. I'm sure I've seen this quesion somewhere, but couldn't find it and neither the answer.

I know `groupBy` is the way to do it probably in the real world, but I'm trying to implement it as close as possible to the original map/reduce logic in the link above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [Scalaz's](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) `|+|` operator because `Maps` are part of the [Semigroup](http://dnene.bitbucket.org/docs/scalaz-guide/ref-identity.html#id1) typeclass:

The `|+|` operator is the Monoid `mappend` function (a Monoid is any "thing" that can be "added" together. Many things can be added together like this: Strings, Ints, Maps, Lists, Options etc. An example:

```
scala> import scalaz._
import scalaz._

scala> import Scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> val map1 = Map(1 -> 3 , 2 -> 4)
map1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 3, 2 -> 4)

scala> val map2 = Map(1 -> 1, 3 -> 6)
map2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 3 -> 6)

scala> map1 |+| map2
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 4, 3 -> 6, 2 -> 4)
```

**So in your case,** rather then create a `List[(String,Int)]`, create a `List[Map[String,Int]]`, and then sum them:

```
val mapped = input.flatMap(_.split(" ").map(word => Map(word -> 1)))
mapped.suml
```

Comment: Nice, didn't play with scalaz yet. Is this a "Guava for Scala" in laymen terms?

Comment: Sort of I suppose. Scalaz is basically a library that "pimps" (using the Pimp my Library pattern) Scala's default libraries, with a few choice components that take ideas from Haskell and category theory. It's designed to let Scala be used in a much more "classically functional" style then the default libraries allow. So you get things like State monads, applicative functors, IO abstractions etc. Stuff that takes a while to understand, but is genuinely useful.

Comment: @EranMedan I would say it Haskell for Scala

Comment: +100 for Scalaz. The sooner you learn it, the better your life!

Comment: Instead of mapped.reduce(_ |+| _) you can just call mapped.suml (no arguments) and get the same result.

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra What is the best way to get the "latest" scalaz jars? got a lot of dead links along the way. Should I build from sources from the github location? (GH removed the downloads feature recently in case they held the binary releases)

Comment: @EranMedan You should be using SBT or Maven for managing dependencies. Otherwise, you can get the Jar from here: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/scalaz/

Comment: @JamesMoore Ah nice. DIdn't know  you could do that.

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra thanks, yep, found the Maven repository eventually. But it became a matter of curiosity as the project page has a link to scala-tools that is broken, so I was wondering what is the old school way to get the binaries. Thanks for the right link!

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra I really tried, but gave up on Scalaz. Did a full sbt project structure, added Scalaz dependency, installed sbteclipse, generated a project, compiles fine, but I get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$ArrowAssoc$.extension$$minus$greater` when running. I guess this deserves a separate question though :)

Comment: Post your SBT build.sbt (use gist.github.com)

Answer (score 8):

You could use a map that returns 0 as default value. Map offers withDefaultValue:

```
def withDefaultValue[B1 >: B](d: B1): Map[A, B1]
```

The same map with a given default value:

```
val emptyMap = Map[String,Int]().withDefaultValue(0)
mapped.foldLeft(emptyMap)((sofar,item) => {
    sofar.updated(item._1, item._2 + sofar(item._1))
})
```

Comment: This works great. I was wishfully thinking there is some magical method in the form `sofar.addgregate(item, _ + _)` and avoid all the `_1` `_2` notation, but I guess this is good enough

Comment: I remember reading a blog about monoids, maps and scalaz. I think it is possible to add to maps with the |+| operator...

Comment: Aside: an alternative to `withDefaultValue` is instead of `sofar(item._1)` use `sofar.get(item._1).getOrElse(0)`

Answer (score 5):

Correct me if I am wrong but how about this:

```
val w = words.groupBy(_.toString).map(x => (x._1,x._2.size)).toList
```

assuming words is the List of words:

```
val words1 = "Hello World Bye World"
val words2 = "Hello Hadoop Goodbye Hadoop"
val words = words1.split(" ") ++ words2.split(" ")
val w = words.groupBy(_.toString).map(x => (x._1,x._2.size)).toList
//List((Goodbye,1), (Hello,2), (Bye,1), (Hadoop,2), (World,2))
```

Answer (score 4):

another version:

```
 val words1 = "Hello World Bye World"             
//> words1  : java.lang.String = Hello World Bye World
 val words2 = "Hello Hadoop Goodbye Hadoop"       
//> words2  : java.lang.String = Hello Hadoop Goodbye Hadoop

 val words = words1.split(" ") ++ words2.split(" ")
//> words  : Array[java.lang.String] = Array(Hello, World, Bye, World, Hello, Hadoop, Goodbye, Hadoop)

 words.map(m => (m, (0 /: words)
   ((x, y) => if (y == m) x + 1 else x))).
     toList.distinct.toMap
 //> res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(Goodbye -> 1, Hello -> 2, Bye -> 1, Hadoop -> 2, World -> 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, most collections are provided with the [groupMapReduce](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMapReduce[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,B]) method which can be seen as a close analog of `Hadoop's map/reduce` logic:

```
val words = List(words1, words2).flatMap(_.split(" "))

words.groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)
// immutable.Map[String,Int] = HashMap(Goodbye -> 1, Hello -> 2, Bye -> 1, Hadoop -> 2, World -> 2)
```

This:

- splits and merges words from the 2 input lists
- `group`s elements by themselves (identity) (group part of **group**MapReduce)
- `map`s each grouped value occurrence to 1 (map part of group**Map**Reduce)
- `reduce`s values within a group of values (`_ + _`) by summing them (reduce part of groupMap**Reduce**).

This is a [one-pass version](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L604) of what can be translated by:

```
words.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.map(_ => 1).reduce(_ + _))
```